# Ipaddress does not show up on netstat

Tags: networking, ip-address, netstat

Why would a ipaddress not show up in foreign address when I do `netstat -atp tcp`?

Here is a list of my foreign address that are not showing up. How can I find out where they are going to?

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           Offload State

  TCP    192.168.0.184:58137    server3005:5938        ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58142    bn3sch020010558:https  ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58204    HPD89D67DFAC36:8080    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58245    ou-in-f188:5228        ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58398    HPD89D67DFAC36:8080    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58542    cache:https            ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58544    234-255-73-208:http    TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58545    a23-78-241-168:http    TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58547    yts2:https             ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    192.168.0.184:58548    234-255-73-208:http    ESTABLISHED     InHost
```

Comment: What do you mean the address is not showing up?  Are you looking for the results that the `-n` switch will give you (`netstat -antp tcp`)?

Comment: Who is 234-255-73-208? or HPD89D67DFAC36? or bn3sch020010558? I want to find out what that connection is.

Comment: Then yes, `-n` is your friend.

Comment: The correct answer is to issue `netcat  -natp`. This will prevent name resolution, and you will instead be shown normal IP addresses.

Comment: The problem then becomes if they do name resolution I loose the strange foreign addresses.

Comment: well, with netstat you have to pick one or the other: numeric output, or resolved. you can't have both.

Comment: When ever I do `netstat -antp tcp` any connection with port `585**` disappears.

Comment: This goes on to another question how do I find out what process is running the connections?  I am running this on windows CMD.

Comment: `-o` displays the owning PID.  `netstat /?` will display all of the switches

Comment: If you're looking for a bit more advanced/easier to use monitor take a look at [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) from SysInternals, which is now Microsoft.